# what is the meaning and difference PVCS version - SVN revision - GIT sha value

Tags: git, svn, pvcs

Can any one help me to know about the difference and the meaning about `PVCS` version number  - `Subversion` revision number - `git` sha value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Subversion`'s revision number is the number of the commit in the repository's chronology. There is nothing magic about it. A newly created `svn` repository is at revision `0`.
Each new commit increases the revision number and gets the new number assigned to it as its revision. The branches does not matter on this process.
On `Subversion`, the revision number of a file is the most recent commit/revision number when the file was modified.

---

Due to its nature and internal working `git` cannot assign sequential numbers to commits. `git` uses `sha1` checksums to identify anything: commits, tags, trees, blobs, files, directories. The `sha1` value is computed using the content of the object it identifies.
There is no relationship between the `sha1` values of related objects but changing the content of an object generates a cascading change of the `sha1` that identifies the objects that depend on it. For example, if you use `git rebase` to move some commits from one branch to another, the `sha1` identifiers of all the moved commits change.

---

I don't know anything about `PVCS`. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

PVCS and SVN are centraliazed repos:

- PVCS use a incremental number per file
- SVN use an incremental number per revision

Git is decentralized, which means it cannot use a number incremented (or it would be incremented concurrently in several distributed cloned repo)

The SHA1 represents the content of a commit (see "[Git Internals - Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)" and "[How is git commit sha1 formed](https://gist.github.com/masak/2415865) ")